# Facebook is not reading Open Graph properties - Meta Tags In Body issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

See this facebook tool to check open graph properties: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.buysell.com%2Freviews%2Fid%2F2599%2F

I don't see any `<meta>` tags in `<body>`, so I don't get why facebook is saying so. Need this fixed because it is affecting user experience when they like / share the link.

http://www.buysell.com/reviews/id/2599/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a  `<noscript>` tag in the head section which is invalid - try removing that and see if facebook's parser can parse it correctly

Comment: can you also recommend having the OG meta tags directly after the opening `head` tag if possible? Wouldn't this make it easier for the parser?

Comment: Ibrahim: it shouldn't make a difference where it is in the `<head>` section, but i assume when the parser finds content that isn't supposed to be in the head it aborts, i'm not sure if it would fail 'safe' in that case and save any valid tags it had detected before the invalid content, or throw them out and abort the entire operation - i suspect the latter

Comment: I don't think so, for some reason the parser is *actually* seeing the OG meta tags outside the `head` tag, inside the `body` tag. if you check the [scraped URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.buysell.com%2Freviews%2Fid%2F2599%2F) you would see that clearly.

Comment: What's output there is the parsed document, not the raw document which was actually retrieved - it usually matches except when the parse tree gets mangled - the raw document served to the parser contains this: http://pastebin.com/yrCyxcNk - tags just inside the </head> tag, with a noscript tag just before that

Comment: Igy, you are on the money. That was it. Once I moved that section to body tag, it's all good. Thanks!

Comment: @Igy, so "*See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL*" means what you said above? On a side note, the pastebin code...is it just a copy/paste from the page source or a *super secret* tool at your end to see what was served to the parser? (maybe just a user-agent switcher? :))

Comment: Ifaour: `alias scrape='curl -i -H '\''Accept: */*'\'' -H '\''Range: bytes=0-40960'\'' -H '\''Connection: close'\'' -A '\''facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)'\'''` - that's as close to the request used by the actual crawler as i know how to get

Comment: Ah then something like the [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) should definitely do the work. thnx